# How can I install ducts on a high place in a building where I can't put nails or screws and where I can't hold ducts to install them?

Tags: ducts

It's a building like that and we need to install ducts at where the red line is. There is no near balconies or windows to help me put the screws in the wall. The ladder can reach up to the blue line that is up to about 5 meters. The remaining is 7 meters. How can I install/drive/put the screws along these 7 meters and install the ducts? I can't fly!

[image]

This is the duct that I'm trying to install:
[image]

The length of a single duct is 2 meters. It is **Plastic (PVC)**. Is it possible two join/weld 3 of them and only fix the lower one into the wall and leave the others unfixed? Or will the wind blow the upper two ones? Are there any other ideas than trying to fly?

Comment: For a single job, rent a longer ladder or scaffolding.  With a ladder should have one or two helpers/watchers.  Duct would only collapse/fall down without being attached to building.

Comment: @crip659 OMG, I'm a new worker so I feel afraid of those long ladders. I feel like I might lose my balance because I'll be holding the heavy screw driver in one hand! A scaffolding is easier but the building is in the desert (No shops, no one to go and rent ..etc).  It'll cost a lot of money to bring a scaffolding and the home owner won't agree I think. The problem is I said yes I can do it. I thought they have everything prepared. I need a magical solution. Thanks for helping! That was useful.

Comment: You need a manlift/scissor lift, the rental is cheaper than setting up a scaffold.

Comment: I re-read the question after I posted an answer.  And I have to wonder what is the duct for? Thinking there is a better solution then what is being considered.

Comment: @GWarner It's a surveillance camera cable and they don't want to show it and protect it.

Comment: @user2824371 Okay. There is no other way to run the wiring? We don't need Fort Knox security but  I would try to avoid running wires where the purpuose of the raceway/duct ends at a camera. Just saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your personal safety, time and the cost of rental equipment that the customer has to cover, look for scissor-lift or 'cherry picker' rentals unique to your area. For this job alone all three factors outweigh the use of scaffolding. Consider this:

> **Greater versatility**: Scissor lifts can be used in almost all the same ways as scaffolding, but are also able to reach areas where scaffolding may not be possible. Scissor lifts often have features like all-terrain wheels and self-leveling that make them operable at a wide range of job sites, and they’re able to get into places scaffolding cannot be installed.
> **Time saving**: Scissor lifts do not require nearly as much space as scaffolding, which means it’s easier and faster to set them up and take them down. The process of installing scaffolding can add a significant amount of time to a construction job, so by having lifts that can be lowered and moved to another location in mere minutes, you drastically cut down on labor time and improve your productivity.
> Lower operating costs: Because scissor lifts save on labor time, that cuts down on operating costs. In addition, you can easily lower and move scissor lifts into storage spaces with much less time and labor, and do not need as much space to store them, which also reduces your operating costs.
> **Protection against workplace injuries**: Scaffolding and ladders are riskier than scissor lifts because their bases are not as stable. Scissor lifts contain outriggers, which offer increased stability for all workers operating at height. Scaffolding and ladders also do not provide the same sort of grip/slip protection for employees when the weather gets wet when you compare them to scissor lifts.
> **No emissions**: If you use scissor lifts with electric engines, you don’t have to worry about creating any extra carbon emissions during the construction process, which makes it an environmentally friendly piece of equipment.
> **Avoid scaffolding dangers**: Scaffolding poses a greater risk of falls and collapse, and requires more inspections. In addition, incorrect planking can make it dangerous. There aren’t nearly as many things that can “go wrong” with scissor lifts as with scaffolding.

*Credit: Ram-Rent-All*

Comment: If the customer doesn't agree to this. Apologize that you are unable to do this job. You are not obligated to do this job in any unsafe manner. That is why I wonder  if doing this from inside might be a better option. Besides what I mentioned in other comments.